# How can I lay out six <div>s in two rows of three columns each?

Tags: css

I am building this site: http://reprezenta.us.lt/

What I need is to position 6 posts in the homepage, in two rows of three, one on top of the other.

I managed to position first 3 posts. Now I need to stack the other 3 in another row underneath first 3 posts.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Note that first column of 220px is not a post.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it correctly, regarding the floating of the posts, the problem here is that they are all different sizes so rather than floating in a clean grid they are filling space created by the second and third post div because the first is too tall.

You need to either insert a clearing element after every three posts using PHP or make each post div the same height so that they are lining up on a clean grid.

Also, you should either make the first column (220px) its own container so that it is not interfering with the content grid or make it tall enough so that it takes up the whole right side. If you are going to place more content under it then I would just give it its own container.

Therefore you would have two parent containers, side bar and content. Side bar contains all elements that belong on the far left and then content contains the repeating post grid.

To see an example of what I mean, regarding the height of the post divs, on line 1512 of styles.css add a fixed height and it will show both the need to separate the side bar and also how to cleanly float the post divs.

```
.news-widget-item {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    height: 420px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways you could do this:

1. Wrap each set of 3 divs inside another div and apply CSS styling as necessary.
2. Add a class or id to the fourth div and then use clear:both for the CSS so that it drops the line down under the other 3 divs (not sure if you will get the 2nd set of 3 divs lining up properly after doing this, just experiment).

Answer (score 1):

You need to change some CSS for the `.column, .columns` selector. At the moment its:

```
float: left;
display: inline;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
```

First of all, an element cannot be displayed inline *and* float. If you float something, it will adapt a block-level display. Anyway, in your case I would try `inline-block` instead:

```
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
vertical-align: top;
```

This will make the elements stack up nicely. It should work in all modern browsers and IE8+ but you might need some CSS trickery for legacy browsers.

This will include the `newspost` element as well, if you want to display it outside, you can do something like:

```
.newspost.columns {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -230px;
}
```

And then adjust the container:

```
.container {
    padding-left: 230px;
    width: 730px;
}
```

[image]